# biblatex bibliography: double hanging indent

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, indentation, biblatex-chicago

For a particular journal which I am submitting to, I must use the Chicago author-date style. So I am using biblatex-chicago style.

But each bibliography item must have double indentation, as shown in the attached image.

I just don't know what to do to fulfill that format requirement, so I would be much obliged if someone helps me out.

[image: Bibliography with double indent]

Comment: That is quite some work. Check out [`biblatex-philosophy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy)'s `philosophy-modern` style. There are lot of options to customise its output and the unmodified output looks quite similar to what you want. Depending on how your journal processes subscriptions it might, however, be a waste of time and effort to try and mirror their output if they do the final typesetting. Maybe you should ask the staff how and if they handle LaTeX submissions and in particular what to do about the bibliography.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the clue. I will check it out and see if I can do something. Thanks again!

Comment: Do get back to us and update us on your progress when you have tried the package.

Comment: I would, but it would take some time, for I have found I need to hack the style files a bit.

Comment: Like I said. Check with the journal staff first. You really don't want to invest that much time only to find out that they are using a different system anyway.

Comment: BTW: If you have any specific questions on how to modify `philosophy-modern` or any other style do not hesitate to ask a question here. Just make sure to include a good [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and an exact description of your problem and we might be able to help you. (Make sure to only ask one question per question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`philosophy-modern` from the [`biblatex-philosophy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy) style family is a good start for this.

With only little change (the `publocformat=loccolonpub` option - which is specific to `biblatex-philosophy`, and `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}`) we get

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=philosophy-modern, publocformat=loccolonpub]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,companion,westfahl:space,brandt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: part of the bibliography section of the MWE]

Comment: I have tried, and I think the philosophy-modern itself has a bug. See the following MWE:

Comment: @ashinpan Can you post a new question with an MWE?

Comment: OK, I will. MWE is longer than permitted here.

Comment: @ashinpan Yes, the comments are not for new questions with MWEs.